# User can edit only it's nodes

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I want to make one website with for instance 10 pages/nodes.

User 1 can edit the node 2, User 2 can edit page 5, User 4 can edit page 4, ...

How can I make this possible with drupal modules without custom dev?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, no modules are needed.
What I've done is :

1. Create Role that can create one specific node type - called fullUser
2. Create role that can only edit it's nodes - called regularUser

Then after, for each user:

1. Create user, set fullUser
2. Connect with this user and create a node
3. Change rone from fullUser to regularUser

Now the user created can only edit it's node

Answer (score 0):

you could create a role for each user (if there are really just 10 nodes/users) and use the [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) Module to controll, who can edit what page...

> This module allows you to manage permissions for content types by role and author. It allows you to specifiy custom view, edit and delete permissions for each content type. **Optionally you can enable per content access settings, so you can customize the access for each content node.**

unfortunately, i'm not totally sure, if this works without any custom development.. you should give it a try

Comment: Cool, i'm collecting infos on this nice Youtube video: www.youtube.com/watch?v=VSQ4L7wADnc